# how can I do a menu list with permission on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display a menu list with the respetives modules that has permission. I have my model,and controller for it, but I dont know how to pass it to my home view and display it. either for php directly or ajax.

controller

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['module'] = 'Login';
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }

    public function getAccess(){
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE){
            redirect('home');
        }else{
            $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
            $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
            $array = $this->user->login($username,$password);
            if ($array[0] == 0) {
                echo 0;
            }else{
                $data_session = array(
                    'id' => $array[0]['id'],
                    'name' => $array[0]['nombre'],
                    'last_name' => $array[0]['apellido'],
                    'type' => $array[0]['id_perfil'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE 
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('log',$data_session);
            }
        }
    } 

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }

    public function getModules($module_id){
        if ($this->session->userdata('log')){
            $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
            $menu = array();
            $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
            foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion) {
                //echo json_encode($seccion);
                $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT concat('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id, storelte_modulo.modulo AS VALUE,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,concat('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) as url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id =  $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.status = 1");
                $seccions[$index]['data']= $modules;
                if(!count($seccions[$index]['data']))
                    unset($seccions[$index]);
            }
            foreach($seccions as $item)
                array_push($menu,$item);
            $this->json($menu);
        }
    }
}
```

module_model

```
class Module extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function get_rows(){
        $this->db->select('id,seccion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_seccion');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

    public function query($query){
        return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    }

}
```

html where will be displayed the modules with permissions

```
<div class="row">
              <h3 class="text-center">Welcome to storeLTE, click a module below to get started!</h3>
              <div class="home_module_list">

              </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to write the modules list via php, you have to pass the $menu array to the view file (html). If you do so, `function getModules()` should:

- return the $menu array, if the getModules() is called from another method of your Controler

-- or --

- pass the array straight to the view file (easiest way for your code example). So, in this case, change your function getModules() on the Controler to:

```
    public function getModules($module_id){
        if ($this->session->userdata('log')){
          $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
          $menu = array();
          $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
          foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion) {
                $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT concat('". $seccion['id'] ."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id, storelte_modulo.modulo AS VALUE, storelte_modulo.seccion_id, concat('". base_url() ."',storelte_modulo.url) as url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id =  $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.status = 1");
                 // assuming you get 1 row only from the above query
                 if (!empty($modules;)) {
                    $modules['index'] = $index;
                    $menu['seccions'] = $modules;
                 }
           }
           $this->load->view('modules_view',$menu);
         }
    }
```

Then in your view file (modules_view.php) you can loop through the $menu items:

```
<div class="row">
<h3 class="text-center">Welcome to storeLTE, click a module below to get started!</h3>
<div class="home_module_list">
  <ul>
  <?php
     foreach($seccions as $session) {
        echo '<li><a href="'. $session['url'] .'">'. $session['index'] .' - '. $session['id'] .' - '. $session['VALUE'] .'</a></li>';
     }
  ?>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

...

If you want to pass the menu via ajax, you have to do it with javascript in your html file, but first your function getModules() should `echo` the JSON array (or the html you are about to embed in the "home_module_list" div). In this case I suggest you give an `id` to the div.